# Generating a Laplace prior from a normal random variable with Rayleigh standard deviation.

Tags: distributions, bayesian, normal-distribution, laplace-distribution

I read on Wikipedia [Laplace distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) that the following is true:

If $X|Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma=Y)$ with $Y \sim \text{Rayleigh}(b)$, then $X \sim \text{Laplace}(\mu, b)$.

However, there doesn't seem to be a reference for it, and I can't manage to prove it myself. Can someone show me why this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the identity 
$$
  I(u,\,v) := \int_0^\infty e^{-u y^2 - v /y^2 } \text{d}y = 
  \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \sqrt{u}}\, e^{-2 \sqrt{uv}} \qquad (u >0, \, v>0). 
$$
which relates (after the change of variable $t:=y^2$) to the Laplace
transform of the function $t \mapsto t^{-1/2} e^{-v / t}$ and its
value at $s = u$, see [N.N. Lebedev Special functions and their
applications](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486606244.html),
footnote of p. 118. The Laplace transform
can be found in the famous book by 
Abramowitz and Stegun as formula (29.3.84) p. 1026.

Now
$$
  p(x) = \int_0^\infty p(x \vert y) \, p(y)\,\text{d}y =
  \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{y \sqrt{2 \pi}}\, e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2y^2)} 
      \times \frac{y}{b^2} \, e^{-y^2/(2b^2)} \,\text{d}y 
$$
and thus $p(x) = I(u,\,v)/(b^2 \sqrt{2 \pi})$ where $I(u,\,v)$ is the
integral above for $u:= 1/(2b^2)$ and $v:= (x - \mu)^2/2$. Using the
value of $I(u,\,v)$ and rearranging, we find $p(x) = \exp\{-|x -
\mu|/b\} / (2b)$ as you claimed.  I do not know how the Laplace transform 
was computed, nor if a simpler derivation exists.

Comment: The formula for $I(u,v)$ can be derived by making the change of variables $z = \sqrt{u} y - \sqrt{v}/y$, so that $uy^2 + v/y^2 = z^2 + 2\sqrt{uv}$.  The Jacobian is messy but most of it cancels, leaving a Gaussian integral over $z$.

Comment: Nice, and simpler! Yet it might be useful to remind that the Laplace transform of an inverse gamma takes a simple form for some values of the shape parameter: here the prior for the precision $1/Y^2$ is inverse gamma.